# Laravel Ubuntu SSL LetsEncrypt Nginx Installation completed but not showing as secure

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I recently installed Letsencrypt on my Ubuntu server based off of the tutorial below.

http://www.jeffmould.com/2016/05/14/install-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-laravel/

I completed all the steps and successfully restarted my server.  When I pull up my webpage, the website still says the connection to this site is not secure.

Is there something potentially missing from this demo that would help me.  Thank you for your help!

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        listen 443;                     #added at ssl
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/laravel/public;#  - PREVIOUSLY USED - ADDED NEXT TWO LINES
#       root /var/www/laravel;
#       location ~ /.well-known { allow all; }


  # these are the paths to our certificate files. You should really only have to
   # change the names of the domain directory, as the file names are consistent with
   # Let's Encrypt.
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDH$
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;


  # this is the path the to dhparam.pem file you created in Step 4
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_tickets off;
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
```

Comment: i don't know if you can listen on 2 ports in one config of a server. You should do 2 config files (one for http and one for https). here is a good tutorial i use every time: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-configure-tlsssl-on-web-server-(nginx)

Comment: i did see that. being as i was doing this after midnight, i actually do have it working to some degree. i have to manually type in the https://mydomain which i guess is a different issue but it looks like laravel may be able to handle that. i'm still curious to know the best way, but does it make a difference if all pages are ssl or just ones with sensitive information these days

Comment: Ssl means more traffic but it is better to secure everything so you can't forget something important